# Find direct and indirect subclasses by scanning filesystem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, java-8, nio

I'm having a problem in writing an algorithm to help me scan a file system and find all subclasses of a certain class.

**Details:**

I've an app that scans an external application using `nio` `Files.walk()` while retrieving I check for "extends SuperClass" while reading the file if the word exits, I add the class name in my list as follows:

```
List<String> subclasses = new ArrayList<>();
Files.walk(appPath)
     .filter(p->Files.isRegularFile(p) && p.toString()
     .endsWith(".java")).forEach(path -> {
        try {
         List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bextends SuperClass\\b");
         Matcher matcher = pattern
                           .matcher(lines.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
         boolean isChild = matcher.find();
         if(isChild) subclasses.add(path.getFileName().toString());
        }catch (IOException e){
                //handle IOE
        }
```

The problem with the above is that it only gets direct subclasses of `SuperClass` but I need to retrieve all direct and indirect subclasses.
I thought about recursion since I've no Idea how many subclasses of `SuperClass` there is but I couldn't implement any reasonable implementation.

**NOTES:**

- Scanning more than 600 thousands file
- I have no Idea how many direct/indirect subclasses of `SuperClass` there is
- The application that I'm scanning is external and I can't modify its code so I'm only allowed to access it by reading files and see where `extends` exists
- If there is a non-recursive solution to the problem that would be great but if there's no other way, I'll be more than happy to accept a recursive one since I care about the solution more than performance.

**Edit:**

I use the following regex to compare both name and import to make sure even in case of same name different packages the output is correct:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("("+superClasss.getPackage()+")[\\s\\S]*(\\bextends "+superClass.getName()+"\\b)[\\s\\S]");
```

I also tried:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bextends "+superClass.getName()+"\\b");
```

But there is also some missing subclasses, I believe that the code bellow skips some checks, and doesn't fully work:

```
public static List<SuperClass> getAllSubClasses(Path path, SuperClass parentClass) throws IOException{
classesToDo.add(baseClass);
while(classesToDo.size() > 0) {
    SuperClass superClass = classesToDo.remove(0);
    List<SuperClass> subclasses = getDirectSubClasses(parentPath,parentClass);
    if(subclasses.size() > 0)
        classes.addAll(subclasses);
    classesToDo.addAll(subclasses);
}
return classes;
```

}

Any help is truly appreciated!

**Edit 2**
I also noticed another problem, is that when I detect a `subclass` I get the file name `currentPath.getFileName()` which might or might not be the subclass name as the subclass may be a `nested` or non-public `class` in the same file.

Comment: There are non-recursive solutions, but it's often much easier to parse a tree via recursion, because a tree is just a recursive data structure. How important is the non-recursiveness to you?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer thanks for replaying :)
I'm scanning more than 900 thousands file, I managed to improve performance by using regex. so it's really important as it may save me hours of unnecessary waiting :)

Comment: There might be a slight missunderstanding. With a non-recursive solution I still mean parsing the file system, but just not using a recursive function for it. There might be the option of using the code and applying reflection, but the code will probably use libraries and I'm not sure you have access to that.

Comment: I guess having recursion for regex type on "class" will be good, and you can create recursive call with base condition of class, as per me NN tree will be suitable for this, but only thing which need to take care is number child node for particular node.

Comment: @Simmant that's something that's really hard to take care of since I've no idea about the number of child nodes :S

Comment: @JeromeReinländer as I said I don't mind doing it recursively, I just couldn't implement it correctly

Comment: hmm, let me check how much dynamic we can make it.

Comment: I will prepare one small code for the same and will share here shortly.

Comment: is all of that source code in the directories following the packages namespace in the source?

Comment: There are far more issues than only getting direct subclasses. A single additional space between `extends` and `SuperClass` (or using multiple line breaks) will make your pattern fail. And what about `extends qualified.package.name.SuperClass`? Or the other way round, what if the simple name `SuperClass` resolves to an entirely different class in a different package or what if `extends SuperClass` is actually inside a `String` literal (`"extends SuperClass"`) or comment (`//  extends SuperClass`)? A regex pattern can not replace a real parser.

Comment: Thanks @Holger you really opened my eyes! I now see more problems and considering a change in the approach but that will take time that I don't have :(  any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a requirement to process the source code files? Processing the compiled class files would be much easier (there are libraries for that), as that’s a single format where all these different ways to say the same thing have been handled already. After all, that’s the entire point of compiling code, to produce a format that can be processed by the computer much easier.

Comment: @Holger yes I can process .class files but I can't use external tools. External libraries to integrate in my repo Maybe! what do u suggest to use while parsing .class files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I strongly recommend parsing compiled class files instead of source code. Since these class files are already optimized for being processed by machines, a lot of the complexity and corner cases of the source code file processing has been eliminated.

So a solution to build a complete class hierarchy tree using the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library would look like this:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> getClassHierarchy(Path root) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(root)
         .filter(p->Files.isRegularFile(p) && isClass(p.getFileName().toString()))
         .map(p -> getClassAndSuper(p))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
}
private static boolean isClass(String fName) {
    // skip package-info and module-info
    return fName.endsWith(".class") && !fName.endsWith("-info.class");
}
private static Map.Entry<String,String> getClassAndSuper(Path p) {
    final class CV extends ClassVisitor {
        Map.Entry<String,String> result;
        public CV() {
            super(Opcodes.ASM5);
        }
        @Override
        public void visit(int version, int access,
                String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
            result = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                Type.getObjectType(name).getClassName(),
                superName!=null? Type.getObjectType(superName).getClassName(): "");
        }
    }
    try {
        final CV visitor = new CV();
        new ClassReader(Files.readAllBytes(p)).accept(visitor, ClassReader.SKIP_CODE);
        return visitor.result;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}
```

As a bonus, resp. to create some test cases, the following method adds the ability to build the hierarchy for a runtime class’ source:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> getClassHierarchy(Class<?> context)
                                        throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Path p;
    URI clURI = context.getResource(context.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI();
    if(clURI.getScheme().equals("jrt")) p = Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/modules"));
    else {
        if(!clURI.getScheme().equals("file")) try {
            FileSystems.getFileSystem(clURI);
        } catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
            FileSystems.newFileSystem(clURI, Collections.emptyMap());
        }
        String qn = context.getName();
        p = Paths.get(clURI).getParent();
        for(int ix = qn.indexOf('.'); ix>0; ix = qn.indexOf('.', ix+1)) p = p.getParent();
    }
    return getClassHierarchy(p);
}
```

Then, you can do

```
Map<String, Set<String>> hierarchy = getClassHierarchy(Number.class);
System.out.println("Direct subclasses of "+Number.class);
hierarchy.getOrDefault("java.lang.Number", Collections.emptySet())
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

and get

```
Direct subclasses of class java.lang.Number
java.lang.Float
java.math.BigDecimal
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
java.lang.Double
java.lang.Long
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
java.lang.Short
java.math.BigInteger
java.lang.Byte
java.util.concurrent.atomic.Striped64
java.lang.Integer
```

or

```
Map<String, Set<String>> hierarchy = getClassHierarchy(Number.class);
System.out.println("All subclasses of "+Number.class);
printAllClasses(hierarchy, "java.lang.Number", "  ");
```

```
private static void printAllClasses(
        Map<String, Set<String>> hierarchy, String parent, String i) {
    hierarchy.getOrDefault(parent, Collections.emptySet())
        .forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(i+x);
            printAllClasses(hierarchy, x, i+"  ");
    });
}
```

to get

```
All subclasses of class java.lang.Number
  java.lang.Float
  java.math.BigDecimal
  java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
  java.lang.Double
  java.lang.Long
  java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
  java.lang.Short
  java.math.BigInteger
  java.lang.Byte
  java.util.concurrent.atomic.Striped64
    java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder
    java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAccumulator
    java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAdder
    java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAccumulator
  java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Hi Holger,  I cannot get maven to identify the library even though I can access its components from intellij.  Is there any special configs that I should do to be able to skip the compilation error. I tried to modify <scope> but didn’t work. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't import that -- import org.objectweb.asm. Have you added a dependency for asm to your pom.xml?

Comment: I think org.objectweb.asm is the correct package — what exactly do you need to know?

Comment: Javassist by [jboss-javassist](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) is also great tool which can parse (and manipulate) class files.. and also has good  Reflection support (ie see what classes this inherits from etc). A tool like this (or ASM) is the correct way to go to achieve with certainty what you want.

Comment: Well, as said, compiled class files are optimized for being processed by machines or, to be more precise, their design is a trade-off between file size and processing speed, but their compact representation helps the performance when we have to read all of them. Compared to a compiler, you made some mistakes, like reading the files to a list of lines, to join them to a giant `String` before processing. Further, you are repeating the `Pattern.compile` step for every file, instead of doing it once before the traversal. If you ever encounter such a text processing task, use `java.util.Scanner`…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the clarification, it makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER: This solution might not work if you have several classes with the same name as it does not take packages names into account.**

I think you can do it with keeping track of the classes to lookup in a `List` and use a while loop until all the values on the list have been explored.

Here is a bit of code which creates a `Map<String, List<String>>`, key is the class name, value is the list of child classes.

```
public class Test {

    private static Path appPath = //your path

    private static Map<String, List<String>> classes = new HashMap<>();
    private static List<String> classesToDo = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        classesToDo.add("AnswerValueValidatorBase");

        while(classesToDo.size() > 0) {
            String className = classesToDo.remove(0);
            List<String> subclasses = getDirectSubclasses(className);
            if(subclasses.size() > 0)
                classes.put(className, subclasses);
            classesToDo.addAll(subclasses);
        }

        System.out.println(classes);
    }

    private static List<String> getDirectSubclasses(String className) throws IOException {
        List<String> subclasses = new ArrayList<>();
        Files.walk(appPath)
             .filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p) && p.toString().endsWith(".java"))
             .forEach(path -> {
                 try {
                      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
                      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bextends "+className+"\\b");
                      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
                      boolean isChild = matcher.find();
                      if(isChild) {
                          String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
                          String clazzName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
                          subclasses.add(clazzName);
                      }
                  } catch(IOException e) {
                  //handle IOE
                  }
        });

        return subclasses;
    }
}
```

Running it on my project returns something that looks correct

```
{
    AnswerValueValidatorBase=[SingleNumericValidator, DefaultValidator, RatingValidator, ArrayValidatorBase, DocumentValidator],
    ArrayValidatorBase=[MultiNumericValidator, StringArrayValidator, IntegerArrayValidator, MultiCheckboxValidator], 
    DefaultValidator=[IntegerValidator, DateValidator, StringValidator, CountryValidator, PercentageValidator], 
    IntegerArrayValidator=[MultiPercentageValidator, RankValidator, MultiDropValidator, MultiRadioValidator, CheckboxValidator], 
    SingleNumericValidator=[SliderValidator], 
    MultiNumericValidator=[MultiSliderValidator], 
    StringArrayValidator=[MultiTextValidator, ChecklistValidator]
}
```

**EDIT**

A recursive way of doing it would be

```
public class Test {

    private static Path appPath = // your path 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> classesToDo = new ArrayList<>();
        classesToDo.add("AnswerValueValidatorBase");

        Map<String, List<String>> classesMap = getSubclasses(new HashMap<>(), classesToDo);

        System.out.println(classesMap);
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> getSubclasses(Map<String, List<String>> classesMap, List<String> classesToDo) throws IOException {
        if(classesToDo.size() == 0) {
            return classesMap;
        } else {
            String className = classesToDo.remove(0);
            List<String> subclasses = getDirectSubclasses(className);
            if(subclasses.size() > 0)
                classesMap.put(className, subclasses);
            classesToDo.addAll(subclasses);
            return getSubclasses(classesMap, classesToDo);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getDirectSubclasses(String className) throws IOException {
        // same as above
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice approach on a small “dataset”. But what about having same class name in different packages, I think that will be an issue :(

Comment: I think we can add a check on package name plus class name but I’m not sure how to implement that

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie The problem with similar names in different packages is that you would have to also check the imports, not only the extends keyword. It gets lot more complicated

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie this might do what you want http://www.class-visualizer.net/ if you don't specifically need to code it yourself.

Comment: I wrote a regex to check for imports and class name, hopefully it will work! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Upvote and accept the answer if it helped! Cheers!

Comment: TI’m still facing some problems with the code if u can help. The algorithm goes one level down and other subclasses are discarded. Any Ideas?

Comment: is all of that source code in the directories following the package namespacing?